# Desabilitar Scroll por um periodo de tempo

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que cria um bloco de carregamento que dura 1 segundo na tela, preciso que quando eu chamo essa função, o scroll da página fique desabilitado por 1 segundo também. Após esse 1 segundo o scroll volta ao normal.

Imagem da animação que me refiro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código JavaScript:

```js
function AnimacaoCarregamento() {
  var block = $('#overlay').parent(); // cria o bloco de carregamento
  $(block).block({
    message: '<i class="icon-spinner4 spinner"></i>',
    timeout: 1000, //unblock after 2 seconds
    overlayCSS: {
      backgroundColor: '#2b2c46',
      opacity: 0.9,
      cursor: 'wait',
    },
    css: {
      border: 0,
      padding: 0,
      color: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
  });

  function setTopo() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
  }
  $(window).bind('scroll', setTopo);
}
```

A função `setTopo()` desabilta o scroll da tela, mas fica desabilitado pra sempre, e preciso que volte ao normal.

Comment: Coloque na sua função um `timeout` que irá habilitar novamente o scroll depois de 1s.  Ficaria assim: `setTimeout(function(){ $('html body').css('overflow', 'visible') },1000)`

Comment: vou tentar, já te retorno se funcionou.

Comment: Editei o comentário e coloquei um exemplo

Comment: @Renan, Vê essa thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily Tem exemplos funcionando - aparentemente - do jeito que você deseja. []´s

Comment: Obrigado Bieno, eu não tinha achado esse link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você apenas precisa passar uma função `callback` no caso `setTimeout` que será disparada X tempo depois que o seu `scroll` ficar escondido.

Deixei o código comentado e defini 2 segundos para a função ser chamada com o intuito do efeito ficar mais perceptível.

```js
$('#btn-bloco').on('click', function(){
   //açoes da função..
   
   /*define o overflow como hidden e passa um timeout que será
   executado depois de 2 segundos voltando o overflow para visible*/
   $('html body').css('overflow', 'hidden', 
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('html body').css('overflow', 'visible')},2000));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
Exemplo de scroll habilitado após 2s
</div> <br>
<button id="btn-bloco"> Chama função </button>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Obrigado Jorge, seu código funcionou aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Solução para remover o scroll da página.
Geralmente o scroll está associado a tag body, vi que você utiliza jQuery então:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Esse trecho de código desabilita o scroll.
No termino da sua função podes colocar algo como.

```
var tempo = 1 //segundos;
setTimeout(() => {$('body').css('overflow','');},tempo * 1000);
```

O css.('overflow','') restaura o padrão antes de ser modificado pelo código acima.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
$('#bt').click(() => {
  $('div').css('overflow','hidden');
  var tempo = 1//segundos;
  setTimeout(() => {$('div').css('overflow','')},tempo * 1000);
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="bt" value="Desabilitar Scroll">
```

Comment: Obrigado Mateus por compartilhar seu conhecimento, vlw pela ajuda.